# Как правильно добавить проверку значения в модуле для DLE?

Tags: php, dle

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно добавить проверку значения из БД на наличие домена в пути у аватаров в модуле для DLE. Спасибо!

```
        $user_photo='';

        if($var['foto']!=''){
            if(strpos($var['foto'], '://')>0){
                $user_photo=$var['foto'];
            }
            else{
                $user_photo=$this->config_dle['http_home_url']."uploads/fotos/".$var['foto'];
            }
        }
        else{
            $user_photo=$this->config_dle['http_home_url']."templates/crimeajournal/dleimages/noavatar.png";
        }

        $this->tpl->set('{user_photo}', $user_photo);
```

Comment: И конкретно в чем здесь ваша проблема?

Comment: Можете в вопросе в каждом иф сделать лог того что в переменный?

Comment: До строки `if($var['foto']!=''){` сделайте `print_($var['foto']); print_($var['foto']); $user_photo=$this->config_dle['http_home_url']`. и напишите ответ в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение следующее. Подсказали, за что огромное спасибо.

```
if( count(explode("@", $var['foto'])) == 2 ) {
    $this->tpl->set( '{user_photo}', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5(trim($row['foto'])) . '?s=' . intval($user_group[$row['user_group']]['max_foto']) );
} else {
    if( $row['foto'] ) {
        $avatar = (strpos($var['foto'], "//") === 0) ? "http:" . $var['foto'] : $var['foto'];

        $avatar = @parse_url($avatar);

        $this->tpl->set( '{user_photo}', ($avatar['host'] ? $var['foto'] : $config['http_home_url'] . "uploads/fotos/" . $var['foto']) );   
    } else $this->tpl->set( '{user_photo}', "{THEME}/dleimages/noavatar.png" );
}
```